# Activate and deactivate usb device in c?

Tags: c, windows

We have a laser scanner which is connected all the time to a certain usb port.
The usb device should be deactivated normally.
Only at certain times I have to activate this usb device at the usb port with a litte c program.
So how can I activate a deactivated usb device in c?
Thanks for your information.

Update:
I forgot to mention to operating system: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, ...
The laser scanner is a Honeywell Voyager MS 9540 product.
In the documentation I read that if the usb scanner is connected to a serial port, you can send enable and disable commands over the serial port in order to enable or disable scanning. But I thought it would be easier to simply enable or disable a usb port/device.

Comment: What do "activated" and "deactivated" mean for your device?

Answer (score 0):

I bit more information would be useful ...

For usb connection you can use [libusb](http://libusb.org/) (see also: [libusb-win32](http://libusb.org/wiki/libusb-win32)). Since it's used by CUPS (a printing software) too, i guess its ideal for you.